# MacOS - SwiftUI, picker dismisses popover

Tags: macos, swiftui, popover, picker

I'm creating a popover for a MacOS app in SwiftUI, but the below picker dismisses the view once a selection is made:

```
    @State private var showPopover: Bool = false
    var strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]
    @State private var selectedStrength = 0

 var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Button("Show popover") {
              self.showPopover = true
        }.popover(
              isPresented: self.$showPopover1,
              arrowEdge: .bottom
          ) {
              Picker(selection: self.$selectedStrength, label: Text("Strength")) {
                   ForEach(0 ..< self.strengths.count) {
                   Text(self.strengths[$0])
              }
          }.frame(width: 200, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Once a selection in the picker is made, the popover dismisses. I need this to stay active, because I want to add further actions to the popover. Does anyone know how I can make sure the popover stays active?

Just to confirm, it's a MacOS app, perhaps MacOS handles it differently from iOS?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a SwiftUI bug - popover interprets click in popup menu as *out-of-bounds-click*, so closed, but should not. If change popup item by keyboard then all works. And there is no possibility to change behaviour as in NSPopover. Worth submitting feedback to Apple.

Comment: Although not the answer I was hoping for, thanks for the feedback. You're right that if you make the selection by keyboard it works just fine. I hadn't seen that yet. What's the best way to submit this to Apple? I'm pretty new to SwiftUI...!

Comment: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com